# How can I amend this streams method to return the Object rather than a List<Object>?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have the below code, and I want to include the `getNames`method in the `List.of` in the `buildAccounts()`, however when I try this I get an error saying that the required type of `List<Account>` doesn't match what's provided which is `List <Object>`. I have tried changing the return type of the `getNames()` to `Account` by adding a `findAny().orElse(null)` which returns the object rather than a List, but this method no longer produces the correct output in `List` format. My question is, what changes do I need to make to allow the `getNames()` to be used in `buildAccounts List.of` without changing the output of the `getNames()`?

```
 public List<Account> buildAccounts(MetaData metaData){
return List.of(
    createAccount(metaData.getAccountName(), metaData.getaccountType()), getNames(metaData, metaData.getaccountType()));
}

public List<Account> getNames(MetaData metadata, AccountType type){
return metaData.getNames().stream()
                              .map(n -> createAccount(n, type))
                              .collect(Collectors.toList());
}


    public Account createAccount(String name, AccountType accountType){
....
}
```

Comment: Should it be `type` instead of `accountType` inside the `getNames` method ?

Comment: Typo my bad thanks

Comment: There is no signature for `List.of()` that matches `List.of(E, List<E>)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you try to add one `Account` (retuned by `createAccount(...)`) to the `List` of `Account` (reurned by `getNames(...)`).

But it does not work like that. `List.of` takes any number of elements of same type and makes a `List` of them.

You will need something like that:

```
public List<Account> buildAccounts(MetaData metaData){
  List<Account> list = new ArrayList<>(getNames(metaData, metaData.getAccountType()));
  list.add(0, createAccount(metaData.getAccountName(), metaData.getAccountType()));
  return list;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that List.of cannot be used that way. If output of getNames cannot change, you'll need to change buildAccounts and not use List.of here.

Since you've tagged this question as streams and used streams in other functions, one way to do it is to create two streams in buildAccounts and combine them.

```
public List<Account> buildAccounts(MetaData metaData){
  Stream firstStream =
    Stream.of(createAccount(metaData.getAccountName(), metaData.getaccountType()));
  Stream secondStream =
    getNames(metaData, metaData.getaccountType()).stream();
  return Stream.concat(firstStream, secondStream).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like the below is the same as what you're trying to achieve?

```
    public List<Account> buildAccounts(MetaData metaData){
           List<Account> accounts = getNames(metaData, metaData.getAccountType());
           accounts.add(createAccount(metaData.getAccountName(), metaData.getaccountType()));
           return accounts;

        }
```